# Error in vapply ... values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[11]]) result is length 0

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've never been very skilled with R and am coming back after an absence so I'm re-learning a lot. I've got a dataset (named data) that has fields latitude and longitude. Some of the observations have '0' in these fields, which is invalid data. I'm writing an R notebook to document my findings.

I have:

````
    Let's start by finding out how many records have 0 for latitude and longitude. If it's a great deal of records, we might not be able to rely on these fields:
```{r}
nrow(filter(data, latitude == 0.0))
nrow(filter(data, longitude == 0.0))
```
Okay, there are 12 rows that have 0 for latitude and 12 rows that have 0 for longitude. I'm willing to bet these are the same rows. Let's find out.

```{r}
filter(data, latitude == 0.0)
```
````

The first two lines that start with nrow() both display the output I expect:

```
[1] 12
[1] 12
```

However, the same filter statement, which I expect to output the 12 rows that match the filter criteria, gives me an error when I run the chunk:

```
Error in vapply(x, obj_sum, character(1L)) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[11]]) result is length 0
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. The 'data' variable is a tibble, if that makes a difference.

I'd sure appreciate an explanation of what's happening here.

Comment: to clarify, it runs without error when you run the code by itself, but throws an error when you run the chunk?  If so, it's likely that `data` exists in your global environment but isn't created when you knit/etc.

Comment: It runs successfully and gives me output in the console, but when part of my notebook it throws this error.

I renamed my variable to a new (unique) name and the problem persists. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: When you knit/etc, think of it as a fresh R environment being created - you'll need to create/load (in a code chunk) whatever isn't there - and `data` might be part of that.

Comment: nrow(filter(data, longitude == 0.0)) works, but taking the inner expression out of the nrow function fails.

Comment: nrow(filter(data, longitude == 0.0)) works, but filter(data, longitude == 0.0) doesn't?

Comment: exactly! :)  Frustrating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136497/discussion-between-matt-tyers-and-nevo).

Answer (score 9):

I don't have the reputation to add a comment, so will provide my 2 cents as an answer though it doesn't actually answer the question.

I got a similar error, and I suspect it is related to list columns in your data. Here is a reproducible example:

````
```{r}
library (dplyr)
library (purrr)

# create data
mydata <- 
  tibble(col_a = rep(c("a", "b"), 5)) %>% 
  mutate(col_b = map(col_a, function (x) { list(a = x, b = x, c = x) }))

# filter
mydata %>% filter (col_a == "a")
```
````

The last line of code performs as expected when I copy/paste it into the console. However, when I runt it from the R-markdown document (using the 'Ctrl+Enter'-shortcut in R-studio) it produces the error:

```
Error in vapply(x, obj_sum, character(1L)) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3
```

The final "length"-part of the error message depends on the length of the list in `col_b`.

Don't know what to make of this. A work around may be to reformat any list columns?

Comment: I'm facing the exact issue today. Works in the console, but not in rmarkdown. What gives?

Answer (score 8):

Your rmarkdown script may contain in-line code that cannot be coerced into a string, before or after your code chunks.

For example, `make_a_graph()` embedded in the text body of the rmarkdown like this:

> Next, we want to `make_a_graph()` with our data.

I solved a similar problem in my script by converting in-line code to chunks one-by-one and the problem went away. Found the tip [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/773).

Comment: I wanted to add that I had in-line code that was printing the output for a shapefile that couldn't be coerced into a string. I didn't receive the error once I fixed those sections of in-line code.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have sufficient reputation to comment, but I also found that an inline 
     `r list(*data_list*)` 
snippet in my R notebook was the culprit for this error. Inserting this segment into a chunk was the solution.

Comment: Same problem but you point the cause : Jupyter. Everything working with Jupyter works on RStudio....except some cases. It works on RStudio but it doesn't work on Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue minutes earlier. I was doing

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!(diff > 0)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(aaa, bbb, ccc, ..., diff, ...)
```

The diff column is different in that it is of the type <drtn>, which is the difference of dates.

I could get rid of either by doing

```
dplyr::mutate(diff = as.numeric(diff)) %>%
```

or remove diff in the select function in the last line.

I guess this is some problem in display instead of sth for calculation.